# fitCopula for Bivariate data in R

Tags: r, package

I am trying for practice to fit a Copula in a sample of two variables using the `copula` and `VineCopula` packages, but I have two questions.

1. First of all my data have values in [0,4] but copulas need the data to be in the interval of [0,1], what is the procedure to convert them without loose their characteristics?
2. The final line of the code it gives an Error, as follows:

   ```r
   fit <- fitCopula(cop_model, m, method = 'ml')
   ```

   > Error in .local(u, copula, log, ...) : unused argument (checkPar = FALSE)

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```r
# z <- my data - I know that is very small!!
   

# the output of dput(z)
structure(c(3.5448, 3.3863, 3.1097, 2.8126, 2.5005, 2.2661, 2.1308, 
            2.0771, 2.0377, 2.0769, 2.0608, 2.3478, 2.8888, 3.2404, 
            3.4623, 3.6302, 3.4086, 3.0667, 2.8401, 2.5854, 2.2845, 2.0605), 
          .Dim = c(11L, 2L))
 
# or 

> z
       [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 3.5448 2.3478
[2,] 3.3863 2.8888
[3,] 3.1097 3.2404
[4,] 2.8126 3.4623
[5,] 2.5005 3.6302
[6,] 2.2661 3.4086
[7,] 2.1308 3.0667
[8,] 2.0771 2.8401
[9,] 2.0377 2.5854
[10,] 2.0769 2.2845
[11,] 2.0608 2.0605

    
m <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(z[, 1], z[, 2])))
selectedCopula <- BiCopSelect(m[, 1], m[, 2], familyset = NA)
selectedCopula
    
# Bivariate copula: Survival Joe (par = 2.11, tau = 0.38) 
# Pseudo observations are the observations in the [0,1] interval. 
# But my data aren't in the [0,1]
            
cop_model <- surJoeBiCopula(selectedCopula$par) 
cop_model
        
# method = mpl or ml
fit <- fitCopula(cop_model, m, method = 'ml') 
fit
```

Comment: Rather than showing `z`, could you attach the output from `dput(z)` to the question? That way others can easily reconstruct it by copy and paste.

Comment: You can transfer you data to be as copula data by using `as.copula` in copula package (as I remember). Using `pobs` transform your data to be in `[0,1]`.

Comment: Thanks @Alice , your suggestion with "pobs" it works fine.